# JDBC - ResultSet cache management

Tags: java, jdbc, fetch, resultset

I'm using this code to load data from a database :

```
PreparedStatement inputStmt = connection.prepareStatement("select * from A");  
inputStmt.setFetchSize(3000);
inputStmt.executeQuery();
```

Since i m using a setFetchSize, I know that the request will fetch only 3000 rows at a time, and if needed it will fetch the next 3000 rows ...

My question is : when we fetch the second 3000 rows, is the first 3000 remains in the cache ?

because I'm reading a table with millions of rows, and if I do not manage well my callc I will have a memory issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `ResultSet` type is `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, meaning that you can only go forward, one row at a time. Unless the driver is very poorly implemented, it won't keep any unaccessible rows in memory anymore.

The default fetch size differs between drivers. Some load the full resultset by default (for example Postgres), others have a smaller fetch size (e.g. Oracle), which can even be ineffective for some types of tasks.

Comment: I m using a ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, is it impacting the cache management ?

Comment: Depends on the driver, but I'd bet that it keeps the rows in memory. Why are you using a scrollable `ResultSet`?

Comment: Because I need to use the isLast() method

Comment: And the driver doesn't support it for a normal resultset? Why do you need `isLast()`?

Comment: Ok, in fact, because I'm splitting what i,m reading into batches using this condition : inputResultSet.getRow() % 3000 == 0 || inputResultSet.isLast();

Comment: That's unnecessary. You can split into batches without using `isLast()`. Keep a custom counter (i.e. `i++`) and iterate the resultset normally. If at the end `i % 3000 != 0` you need to handle the extra smaller batch. It's a pretty standard idiom.